# Video Recorder inside a app using xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, video-recording

How can I implement a video recorder inside an application using xamarin forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Xamarin.Plugin.Media. If it is not flexible enough for you, then you need to implement the video recorder using the native APIs. In which case you probably shouldn't be doing Xamarin.Forms at all, but if you insist that is the way.

Comment: can u please refer any link for implement video recorder using the native APIs.

Comment: @Maglin you can use any tutorial for iOS and Android and translate it to C#. Also you have the code of Xamarin.Plugin.Media on github, so you can use it for the start if that's preferable and alter it further, that codes uses native APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to achieve the result like following GIF(Over 2M, SO cannot allow upload it )?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0Knx.jpg

I achieve it in android by custom rendere. Here is code.

First of all, we should `MediaRecorder` to record the video.

```
   public void startRecord(SurfaceView surfaceView)
    {

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {

            string path = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/test.mp4";
            recorder = new MediaRecorder();

            //If you want to rotate the video screen, you can use following code
            //Camera camera = Camera.Open();
            //Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.GetParameters();

            //parameters.SetPreviewSize(640, 480);
            //parameters.SetPictureSize(640, 480);
            //camera.SetParameters(parameters);
            //camera.SetDisplayOrientation(90);
            //camera.Unlock();
            //recorder.SetCamera(camera); 

                recorder.SetVideoSource(VideoSource.Camera);
                recorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Mic);
                recorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Default);
                recorder.SetVideoEncoder(VideoEncoder.Default);
                recorder.SetAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.Default);
                recorder.SetOutputFile(path);
                recorder.SetPreviewDisplay(surfaceView.Holder.Surface);
                recorder.Prepare();
                recorder.Start();

        });

    }
```

If you want to achieve the record the video inside the application, you should use custom renderer to view. Use `SurfaceView` to see the camera view.First of all. please create a `CameraPreview`

```
    public sealed class CameraPreview : ViewGroup, ISurfaceHolderCallback
{
    public SurfaceView surfaceView;
    ISurfaceHolder holder;
    Camera.Size previewSize;
    IList<Camera.Size> supportedPreviewSizes;
    Camera camera;
    IWindowManager windowManager;
    MediaRecorder recorder;

    public bool IsPreviewing { get; set; }

    public Camera Preview {
        get { return camera; }
        set {
            camera = value;
            if (camera != null) {
                supportedPreviewSizes = Preview.GetParameters().SupportedPreviewSizes;
                RequestLayout();
            }
        }
    }

    public CameraPreview (Context context)
        : base (context)
    {
        surfaceView = new SurfaceView (context);
        AddView (surfaceView);

        windowManager = Context.GetSystemService (Context.WindowService).JavaCast<IWindowManager>();

        IsPreviewing = false;
        holder = surfaceView.Holder;
        holder.AddCallback (this);


        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string>("111", "Hi", (expense) =>
        {
            startRecord(surfaceView);
        });

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string>("1112", "Hi2", (expense) =>
        {
            stopRecord(surfaceView);
        });


    }

    private void stopRecord(SurfaceView surfaceView)
    {
        recorder.Stop();
        recorder.Release();
    }

    public void startRecord(SurfaceView surfaceView)
    {

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {

            string path = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/test.mp4";
            recorder = new MediaRecorder();

            //If you want to rotate the video screen, you can use following code
            //Camera camera = Camera.Open();
            //Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.GetParameters();

            //parameters.SetPreviewSize(640, 480);
            //parameters.SetPictureSize(640, 480);
            //camera.SetParameters(parameters);
            //camera.SetDisplayOrientation(90);
            //camera.Unlock();
            //recorder.SetCamera(camera); 

                recorder.SetVideoSource(VideoSource.Camera);
                recorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Mic);
                recorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Default);
                recorder.SetVideoEncoder(VideoEncoder.Default);
                recorder.SetAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.Default);
                recorder.SetOutputFile(path);
                recorder.SetPreviewDisplay(surfaceView.Holder.Surface);
                recorder.Prepare();
                recorder.Start();

        });




    }


    protected override void OnMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        int width = ResolveSize (SuggestedMinimumWidth, widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = ResolveSize (SuggestedMinimumHeight, heightMeasureSpec);
        SetMeasuredDimension (width, height);

        if (supportedPreviewSizes != null) {
            previewSize = GetOptimalPreviewSize (supportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnLayout (bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        var msw = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec (r - l, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);
        var msh = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec (b - t, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);

        surfaceView.Measure (msw, msh);
        surfaceView.Layout (0, 0, r - l, b - t);
    }

    public void SurfaceCreated (ISurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        try {
            if (Preview != null) {
                Preview.SetPreviewDisplay (holder);
             }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (@"          ERROR: ", ex.Message);
        }
    }




    public void SurfaceDestroyed (ISurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        if (Preview != null) {
            Preview.StopPreview ();
        }
    }

    public void SurfaceChanged (ISurfaceHolder holder, Android.Graphics.Format format, int width, int height)
    {
        var parameters = Preview.GetParameters ();
        parameters.SetPreviewSize (previewSize.Width, previewSize.Height);
        RequestLayout ();
        //If you want to rotate the video screen, you can use following code
        //switch (windowManager.DefaultDisplay.Rotation) {
        //case SurfaceOrientation.Rotation0:
        //  camera.SetDisplayOrientation (90);
        //  break;
        //case SurfaceOrientation.Rotation90:
        //  camera.SetDisplayOrientation (0);
        //  break;
        //case SurfaceOrientation.Rotation270:
        //  camera.SetDisplayOrientation (180);
        //  break;
        //}

        Preview.SetParameters (parameters);
        Preview.StartPreview ();
        IsPreviewing = true;
    }

    Camera.Size GetOptimalPreviewSize (IList<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h)
    {
        const double AspectTolerance = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double)w / h;

        if (sizes == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = double.MaxValue;

        int targetHeight = h;
        foreach (Camera.Size size in sizes) {
            double ratio = (double)size.Width / size.Height;

            if (Math.Abs (ratio - targetRatio) > AspectTolerance)
                continue;
            if (Math.Abs (size.Height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.Abs (size.Height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = double.MaxValue;
            foreach (Camera.Size size in sizes) {
                if (Math.Abs (size.Height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.Abs (size.Height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }

        return optimalSize;
    }
}
```

Then, Here is custom renderer.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomRenderer.CameraPreview), typeof(CameraPreviewRenderer))]
```

namespace CustomRenderer.Droid
{
    public class CameraPreviewRenderer : ViewRenderer
    {
        CameraPreview cameraPreview;

```
    public CameraPreviewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }



protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomRenderer.CameraPreview> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            // Unsubscribe
            cameraPreview.Click -= OnCameraPreviewClicked;
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            if (Control == null)
            {
                cameraPreview = new CameraPreview(Context);


                SetNativeControl(cameraPreview);
            }
            Control.Preview = Camera.Open((int)e.NewElement.Camera);

            // Subscribe
            cameraPreview.Click += OnCameraPreviewClicked;
        }




    }

    void OnCameraPreviewClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cameraPreview.IsPreviewing)
        {
            cameraPreview.Preview.StopPreview();
            cameraPreview.IsPreviewing = false;
        }
        else
        {
            cameraPreview.Preview.StartPreview();
            cameraPreview.IsPreviewing = true;
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            Control.Preview.Release();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }


 }
 }
```

If you want to know how to achieve Camera Preview in the IOS or UWP, you can refer to this link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view

Here is code in github.

https://github.com/851265601/FormsRecordVideoInside

Above way to achieve it, it a bit complexed. I suggest you to use the `Xam.Plugin.Media` to achieve it. Here is running GIF. it cannot see the video preview in the application, but you do not need to use custom renderer to achieve it just serveral lines code.

```
  private async void PlayStopButtonText_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //  throw new NotImplementedException();

        var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakeVideoAsync(new StoreVideoOptions
        {
            SaveToAlbum = true,Directory = "Sample"


        });

        //Get the public album path

        if (file == null)
            return;

        await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.AlbumPath, "OK");
    }
```

In the android, add the following permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Here is running GIF(Over 2M, SO cannot allow upload it ).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Nu93.jpg

Comment: thank u, this is working fine but how to achieve in front camera ? its working Back side camera only, Can you Please help me

Comment: @Maglin If you use custom renderer way to achieve it. you can change the layout code like `<local:CameraPreview Camera="Front" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />` In the CameraPreview class. has define the Front  carmera. If you use the `Xam.Plugin.Media` You can use `DefaultCamera= CameraDevice.Front` in the  `  var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakeVideoAsync(new StoreVideoOptions
            {
                SaveToAlbum = true,Directory = "Sample",DefaultCamera= CameraDevice.Front
            });`